# How do I use an attribute to get a JSON value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a link with a 'rel' attribute:

```
<a href="#" rel="music">Click</a>
<p></p>
```

I have a variable containing JSON:

```
var myStyle = {
"music": { "band": "Beatles", "type": "Rock"},
    "movie": { "title" "Shrek", "type": "Kids"}
};
```

I want to use jQuery to get values from JSON according to the 'rel' attribute:

```
$('a').click(function() {
      var whatLink = $('a').attr('rel');
    $('p').text(myStyle.whatLink.band);
});
```

I see that the value of "style" is "music" but the result of clicking the link is

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'band' of undefined

Is it even possible?

Comment: `rel` "describes the relationship from the current document to the anchor specified by the href attribute". It is not a place for you to store arbitrary data. Use HTML 5's data-* attributes for that.

Comment: That variable contains a JavaScript `Object`, not JSON.

Comment: @Quentin: Though lightboxes will have you believe it is. :P

Comment: Guess I should have mentioned i'm a newbie.

Comment: Qeuntin - Thanks for the tip.
All 3 answers where identical so I chose the one that answered first. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using...

```
$('a').click(function() {
      var whatLink = $('a').attr('rel');
    $('p').text(myStyle[whatLink].band);
});
```

...`whatLink` is always gonna give you the `rel` value of the last (or first, can't remember) `a` in your page. To really check the `rel` value of the link you just clicked, use `this` instead of `'a'` in the selector inside the event. Like so...

```
$('a').click(function() {
      var whatLink = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('p').text(myStyle[whatLink].band);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('a').click(function() {
      var whatLink = $('a').attr('rel');
    $('p').text(myStyle[whatLink].band);
});
```

When accessing properties using variables, *dot operator* does not work and you have to use *dictionary/array operator*.

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'band' of undefined

This is because the `whatLink` property does not exist of `myStyle`, therefore returning `undefined`, which of course has no `band` property.

Use bracket notation...

```
$('a').click(function() {
      var whatLink = $('a').attr('rel');
    $('p').text(myStyle[whatLink].band);
});
```

...otherwise `whatLink` is taken literally.